# How to get controlinfo in ppp module in inet (version 4) framework

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am not new in OMNET++ simulation, but this is challenging to me.

I want to develop some sniffing  functionality that needs to get source and destination addresses. My code is based on ppp module. I tried many ways but I get either simulation halt unexpectedly or invalid operation.

I tried:

```
auto *info = packet->getControlInfo();
```

then

```
EV_INFO<<" Details"<<info.detailedinfo;
```

Anyone will help it will be much apprecaited

Thank you

Comment: What version of INET do you use?

Comment: I am using INET 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since INET 4.x Control Info is no longer used. Instead, Chunks and Tags have been introduced. Take a look at [INET Developer’s Guide - Working with Packets](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-packets.html).
In short, in order to obtain an address from PPP header the following code code may be used:

```
auto packet = check_and_cast<Packet *>(msg);
const auto& pppHeader = packet->peekAtFront<PppHeader>();
auto addr = pppHeader->getAddress();
```

By the way: PPP frame does not have neither source nor destination address.

Comment: Thank you Jerzy D. thank you very much for your reply ... it is very useful piece of code. It works fine and gets me 255 for every packet. My question now is how to get ip addresses while packets travelling through routers.  I got all what I need. Only  ip addresses for source and destination are missing. I got the duration, arrival time, length in bytes, queue size etc.

Comment: You should decapsulate a PPP packet, take payload and then take IPv4 header - in the similar way as in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I got it. It works great now. Thanks a lot.